# My question is on the working of OR operator in SQL, can it be used to combine two selection queries

Tags: sql, sqlite

```
SELECT student.name 
FROM student
WHERE student.email = copy.owner AND copy.book = "978-0262033848" 
OR
SELECT student.name 
FROM student
WHERE student.email = loan.borrower AND loan.book = "978-0262033848";
```

In this code, I tried to combine two queries. It is displaying an error and I would like to know what is the mistake in using it this way

Comment: Neither query would work independently.  Perhaps you should explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please post sample data for all tables involved.

Comment: I am trying to select the names of students from the student table whose mail I’d is  same as that in copy table and select the names of students from student table whose mail I’d is same as that in loan table at the same time the ISBN13 no should be 978-0262033848

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that this does what you want:

```
SELECT s.name
FROM student s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM copy c
              WHERE c.email = c.owner and c.book = '978-0262033848'
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM loan l
              WHERE s.email = l.borrower and l.book = '978-0262033848'
             );
```

This select students that are in the `loan` or `copy` tables with the specified book.

Comment: Thanks for answering, this works: but I am new to SQL so I don't understand  why I cant join independent queries using OR whereas in your answer two selection queries has been joined using OR operator

Comment: @Tom . . . `OR` is a boolean operation that works on boolean expressions.  The result of a query is simply not a boolean expression (something that evaluates to "true" or "false").  That is not what `or` does.  SQL does offer set based operators -- `UNION ALL`, `INTERSECT`, and so on.  Perhaps one of those could be used.